# What is the study of body language and speech and what it means the person is feeling or thinking?

Tags: body-language

To clarify i mean like how when someone doesn't use contractions it is a red flag for lying. Or when someone says something they are mad or annoyed. Basically what their speech and body language says about what they are thinking/feeling.
Stuff that the main character in Lie To Me uses like body language, speech changes and micro expressions.

Comment: So are you asking if this field has a specific name?